# How can I redefine the current label?

Tags: hyperref, cross-referencing, algorithm2e, backref

I'm having back reference issues when using an algorithm.

Consider the following example

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[algo2e,linesnumbered,algonl]{algorithm2e}
\usepackage[backref=section]{hyperref}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@misc{myarticle,
    author  = {ABC},
    title   = {A Title},
    year    = {2023},
}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}

\section{Test}
\subsection{Test}
\subsubsection{Test}

% comment/uncomment the algorithm
\begin{algorithm2e}
$a=b$\;
$b=c$\;
$c=d$\;
\end{algorithm2e}

\paragraph{Test}

Citing~\cite{myarticle}.

\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{\jobname}

\end{document}
```

The back reference picks up the the last line number of the algorithm as the last label, apparently, instead of the last section.  If the algorithm is commented out, I see the expected behavior, and the back reference refers to the section.

### *with the algorithm*

[image]

### **without the algorithm:**

[image]

Any ideas on a fix?  It seems that `\@currentlabel` is overwritten in the algorithm.  Can the section label be stored before the algorithm and restored after the algorithm?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`backref=section` doesn't actually pick up the section level. For instance, if you do

```
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}
```

and

```
\begin{theorem}
Something with \cite{myarticle}
\end{theorem}
```

the back reference will show the theorem number (test it). What actually happens is that `hyperref` picks up the current value of `\@currentlabel` that's by no means guaranteed to be the current section number.

In common cases this *seems* to work, provided your `\cite` commands aren't in environments that do their own numbering (such as `theorem` above).

So this ought to work with the `algorithm2e` environment, you say. No, sorry. The reason is that `algorithm2e` does a *Bad Thing*™, namely

```
\gdef\@currentlabel{...}
```

in connection with line numbering, so at the point of usage of your `\cite` command, `\@currentlabel` points to the last line number in the algorithm.

Conclusion: `backref=section` isn't reliable.

#### Full example.

```
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@misc{myarticle,
    author  = {ABC},
    title   = {A Title},
    year    = {2023},
}
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[algo2e,linesnumbered,algonl]{algorithm2e}
\usepackage[backref=section]{hyperref}

\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}
\renewcommand{\thetheorem}{!!!\arabic{theorem}!!!}% very distinctive

\begin{document}

\section{Test}
\subsection{Test}
\subsubsection{Test}

\cite{myarticle}

% comment/uncomment the algorithm
\begin{algorithm2e}
$a=b$\;
$b=c$\;
$c=d$\;
\end{algorithm2e}

\paragraph{Test}

\cite{myarticle}

\begin{theorem}Citing~\cite{myarticle}.\end{theorem}

\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{\jobname}

\end{document}
```

[image]

#### Possible workaround (with many limitations)

```
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@misc{myarticle,
    author  = {ABC},
    title   = {A Title},
    year    = {2023},
}
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[algo2e,linesnumbered,algonl]{algorithm2e}
\usepackage[backref=section]{hyperref}

\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}
\renewcommand{\thetheorem}{!!!\arabic{theorem}!!!}% very distinctive

\makeatletter
\NewCommandCopy{\original@cite}{\cite}
\RenewDocumentCommand{\cite}{om}{%
  \begingroup
  \restore@sectional@label
  \IfNoValueTF{#1}{\original@cite{#2}}{\original@cite[#1]{#2}}%
  \endgroup
}
\newcommand{\restore@sectional@label}{%
  \protected@edef\@currentlabel{%
    \ifnum\value{subsubsection}>0 \thesubsubsection\else
    \ifnum\value{subsection}>0 \thesubsection\else
    \thesection\fi\fi
  }%
}
\makeatother


\begin{document}

\section{Test}

\cite{myarticle}

\subsection{Test}

\cite{myarticle}

\subsubsection{Test}

\cite{myarticle}

% comment/uncomment the algorithm
\begin{algorithm2e}
$a=b$\;
$b=c$\;
$c=d$\;
\end{algorithm2e}

\paragraph{Test}

\cite{myarticle}

\begin{theorem}Citing~\cite{myarticle}.\end{theorem}

\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{\jobname}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: we should get algorithm2e to not use gdef or (simpler) save and restore `\@current;label` for the enviornment so at least locally it restores correctly at the end?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Getting bugs fixed in `algorithm2e` is a dead attempt.

Comment: LPPL............

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I cannot recommend `algorithm2e` over other similar packages. Anyway, as I showed, `backref=section` isn't reliable.

Comment: well there is that too

Comment: @egreg -- thank you for thoroughly explaining this.  Resetting the `\@currentlabel` around cite to the section number  with your workaround worked perfectly for me (so far).